# Why does my image go outside of the bootstrap grid?

Tags: html, css

I have created a 3 column grid which contains some text and an image in between using Bootstrap 4 for the grid system.

I've noticed that although my image has a `img-fluid` class assigned the image overflows outside the div.

Can anyone explain the reason for this?

HTML

```
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col blue-bg-outter">
      <div class="col blue-bg" style="height: 300px;">

        <!-- start of content -->
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col">
            <h2> Some line</h2>
          </div>
          <div class="col img-col">
            <img src="https://purepng.com/public/uploads/large/51508089516arw4tqfangou1wmvwzihlw7hxnzjujpulweq1otwrsdcsaxc5kvmu1crkpcyfxezyx4dmcvkbgg5w7oc1sioxib4j044tjwbfcyu.png" alt="" class="img-fluid">
          </div>
          <div class="col">
            <h2> Another line</h2>
          </div>
        </div>

      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

CSS

```
.img-fluid {
  max-height: 100vh;
}

.blue-bg-outter { 
  padding: 60px;
}

.blue-bg { 
  background: #3ad7f7;
}
```

Might be easier to see on an actual page, please view the [CodePen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/pqMzyJ).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you have set a height on a parent div to `300px`, if you remove height it works. Or you can set the height of `img-fluid` to `300px` as @august suggested:

```
<div class="col blue-bg">
```

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/oJKvLp

Or you can keep the height and stop the image overflowing like this:

```
.blue-bg
{
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

Comment: Changing max-height of .img-fluid to 300px instead of 100vh would make the image fit according to parent div as well.

Comment: Yea, just tried it. That's probably the solution. I'm not sure exactly what OP is trying to achieve but I think you've got it : )

Answer (score 0):

To keep the image size responsive to the bootstrap column, this was doing the trick for me:

```html
<div class="col-md-3">
    <img class="img-responsive" width="100%" src="your-image-path">
</div>
```